# New instance in TWebBrowser

Tags: delphi, twebbrowser

I would like to use the TWebBrowser Component in a complete new instance independently from the instance of the Internet Explorer. Is there a way to start TWebBrowser (e.g. in private browsing mode) so it would have it's own instance of cookies, cache, history, etc.?

Comment: Hi Benjamin, I am afraid that Twebbrowser shares IE's settings / cache. There is no private browsing mode in TWebbrowser. What I learned from our last discussion is that you want to auto-fill form fields with username/password and so on, you will need to develop a browser addin, if you don't want to reinvent the wheel, please check out https://lastpass.com/

Comment: @whosrdaddy, is that lastpass open-sourced? If no, why it worth to mention?

Comment: @user539484:  no it is a free utility that does what the OP wants to achieve (from an earlier related question that is now deleted). It is a good starting point to see what he needs to do/implement if he wants to make this himself...

Comment: Thanks for the tip. Greg M. has made an answer.

Comment: Check out this one: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/ieextensiondevelopment/thread/9793932f-8047-4469-947e-12a21f4b3d0c/

Comment: Really great link! Thank you so much. This would actually work if I start the ie in private mode and get the instance of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [delphi chromium](http://code.google.com/p/delphichromiumembedded/).
Based on Chrome browser, fully autonomous and more html5 compliant....
You can define the directory where to store cookies, and then, clean them as you like...

Comment: Thank you. So I guess it is NOT possible to do so.

Comment: This does not answer the question that was asked. Please do try to do that.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan : The question is to have an autonomous browser. Sure, it's not the TWebbrowser... Copying the few libraries needed and you can definitly have it with a complete delphi integration. Not so bad no ?

Comment: @GregM. The question is, to quote verbatim, "Is there a way to start TWebBrowser (e.g. in private browsing mode) so it would have it's own instance of cookies, cache, history, etc.?"

Comment: ok. i meant to give an alternative instead of a 'No...'. i was too constructive ^^

Comment: But you did not say that it cannot be done in `TWebBrowser`. You should at least answer that before going on to be constructive.